# Cut a table halfway in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

My sheet contains of cars that are placed at a certain location and need to be checked. This list is made twice a day and sometimes contains of 10 rows, sometimes 14, sometimes 12 etc. Now I would like to cut half of the rows and place it next to the other rows (in this case paste it in cell E). I would like to automate this process so in the VBA should be:

- Count number of rows (X)
- Cut the rows from X/2 to X
- Paste the data in cell E1

I found this function which returns the middle cell. However, I would like to put this together in a sub.

```
Function Middle(r As Range) As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
   If r.Columns.Count > 1 Then
       Middle = [#N/A]
       Exit Function
   End If
  i = r.Row
  j = r.Rows.Count
  Middle = Cells(i + (j - 1) / 2, r.Column).Address
End Function

Sub cutting()
        Range("Middle:C" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("E2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A1:C1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("E1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("E8").Select
    End Sub
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqgCq.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2d56.png)

Comment: Two image is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to select the data to work with it.
Try:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lCutRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet.
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column A.
        If lLastRow > 1 Then
            lCutRow = (lLastRow / 2) + 1
            .Range(.Cells(lCutRow, 1), .Cells(lLastRow, 3)).Cut Destination:=.Cells(1, 5) 'Paste to row 1, column 5 (E1).
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```